about useing photo in django
enter image description here
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Food (models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tozih=models.CharField(("tozih"), max_length= 50)
    rate=models.IntegerField(("score"))
    price=models.IntegerField()
    
    pub=models.DateField(("when"), auto_now= False , auto_now_add= True)
    p2hoto=models.ImageField(upload_to='foods/' , max_length= 20000 )

i want to in my admin page upload a image but is giving me this

Errors and output, like code, should not be provided as images if they are available as text as is the case here.

i want to in my admin page upload a image but is giving me this PLEASE WHAT ERROR ARE YOU SEEING? What you have in the image is not an error but an output because you tried to modify your models and that is normal

You can provide a default value of 1 to migrate your models

Well as the error says, you added p2hoto, but since you already made the model, there can already be records. So the question is, what should p2hoto do for the existing Food records?

You migrated before add the p2hoto field and add save some data in Food model, so when you add this field and migrate, those data want an image because your p2hoto field isn't null and doesn't have any default item.
Do one of these:

Set default to the p2hoto field:
p2hoto=models.ImageField(upload_to='foods/' , max_length= 20000, default='you-image-path')


Set null to the field:
p2hoto=models.ImageField(upload_to='foods/', max_length=20000, null=True`)



